# passing coordinates to d3js from asp.net server side showing null

Tags: c#, asp.net, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on data visualization on map using d3js. i was able to show the map which if i put static coordinates it'll show marker on map. but what i want to do is fetching coordinates from database and showing marker on the map, though passing the coordinates from the server side to d3js is where i'm having problem. i have gone through some questions relating to this which has really helped me so far but i'm stucked here as the method passed to d3js is showing null value.

```
    var width = window.innerWidth,
                height = window.innerHeight;

            // create svg for viz
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            // define JSON map data
            d3.json("NGA_adm2_conv.json", function (json) {
                // create a first guess for the projection
                var center = d3.geo.centroid(json);
                var scale = 3000; //150;//8000;
                var offset = [width / 2, height / 2];

                var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                    .center(center)
                   // .rotate([85.8, 0])
                    .scale(scale)
                    .translate(offset);

                var geoPath = d3.geo.path()
                    .projection(projection);

                svg.append("g")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(json.geometries)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("d", geoPath)   
                    .attr("class", "areas")
                    .attr("fill", "Steelblue");
                // Create data for circles:

               //passing method to var marker then to d3
                var markers = '<%= JasonGet() %>';
                // Add circles:
                svg
                  .selectAll("myCircles")
                  .data(markers)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0] })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1] })
                    .attr("r", 4)
                    .style("fill", "69b3a2")
                    .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("fill-opacity", .4)

            });


//below is my asp.net c# code for fetching coordinates from database 

    public string jsonString = "";
            [WebMethod]
            public string JasonGet()
            {
                var queryWithForJson = "SELECT  latitude, longitude FROM tblCoordinates FOR JSON AUTO";
                var conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
                conn.Open();
                var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                {
                    jsonResult.Append("[]");
                }
                else
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    }
                }
                Label1.Text = jsonResult.ToString();
               return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonResult);
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting data from a file, and also code-behind. [Here's a link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js#d3.json) for using a file. If you want data from code-behind, search `Page Methods` or `Web Methods` or `ASP.NET Web Services (asmx)`.

Comment: i'm trying the web service but its returning null in d3js data

Comment: i have worked on web service but it kept showing null when i put the link to the web service method